# Unable to use coq's NDiv after importing

Tags: coq

I am trying to use the functionality from NDiv in coq's standard library (visible here: https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Numbers.Natural.Abstract.NDiv.html), so I enter the two lines below into coqide:

```
Require Import NDiv.
Check div_unique_exact.
```

But it results in an output of

```
Error: The reference div_unique_exact was not found in the current environment
```

I am not sure where the problem is. I also use imports such as List Arth Bool and Classical_Prop without problem. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `NDiv` starts with

```
Module Type NDivProp (Import N : NAxiomsSig')(Import NP : NSubProp N).
```

The entire file is wrapped in this `Module Type`, which means that every lemma you see is only defined when you pass in module arguments to this module type functor.  You probably want something like `Require Import NArith.` (or `Require Import ZArith.`), whence you can see if Coq can find `div_unique_exact` with `Locate`.  If I do

```
Require Import Coq.NArith.NArith.
Locate div_unique_exact.
```

I get

```
Constant Coq.NArith.BinNat.N.div_unique_exact
  (shorter name to refer to it in current context is N.div_unique_exact)
Constant Coq.ZArith.BinInt.Z.Private_Div.NZQuot.div_unique_exact
  (shorter name to refer to it in current context is BinInt.Z.Private_Div.NZQuot.div_unique_exact)
Constant Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.Nat.div_unique_exact
  (shorter name to refer to it in current context is PeanoNat.Nat.div_unique_exact)
Constant Coq.NArith.BinNat.N.Private_NZDiv.div_unique_exact
  (shorter name to refer to it in current context is N.Private_NZDiv.div_unique_exact)
Constant Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.Nat.Private_NZDiv.div_unique_exact
  (shorter name to refer to it in current context is PeanoNat.Nat.Private_NZDiv.div_unique_exact)
Constant Coq.ZArith.BinInt.Z.Private_NZDiv.div_unique_exact
  (shorter name to refer to it in current context is BinInt.Z.Private_NZDiv.div_unique_exact)
Constant Coq.ZArith.BinInt.Z.div_unique_exact
  (shorter name to refer to it in current context is BinInt.Z.div_unique_exact)
```

and so we see that the first entry shows that the following will succeed:

```
Check N.div_unique_exact.
```